# Two right joins / right + outer join, etc not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables:

Salesman table (containing all salesman ID numbers and their names), a week number table (just a table with 53 numbered entries), and a sales data table with all sales.

I need an output of all salesman, all weeks, even if 0. I can get a list of all weeks, or all salesman, but not both.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
DATEPART(wk, d1.u_date) as 'Week', 
d4.week AS 'AllWeeks',
convert(decimal,d1.U_slsm) as 'Salesman', 
S1.SalesmanNum   

from [test].[dbo].[@ORDERLOG] D1
right outer join [test].[dbo].[@weekcounter] d4 on (d4.week = DATEPART(wk, d1.u_date) and DATEPART(yy, d1.u_date) > 2014)
full outer join (select salesmannum from EXECUTIVE...Salesman) S1 on convert(decimal,d1.U_slsm) = S1.salesmannum 

order by d4.Week, S1.SalesmanNum
```

This gives me all 53 weeks even if there are no sales (desired), and it gives me all the salesman who had sales each week (desired), but it only gives me one instance of all the salesman who didn't have sales. I need all salesman for each week. 20 salesman, 53 weeks, 1060 results. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

This will ultimately include sales data, but I can't get this much to work so far...

I have tried many combinations of joins to no avail...
This is in MSSQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all combinations of salesman and week number you can use a `cross join` between the tables to generate the cartesian product of the two sets.

Your query would look something like this (adjust source tables names as needed):

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(wk, d1.u_date) as 'Week', 
    all_salesman_weeks.week AS 'AllWeeks',
    convert(decimal,d1.U_slsm) as 'Salesman', 
    all_salesman_weeks.SalesmanNum   
from (
  select * from 
  EXECUTIVE...Salesman 
  cross join 
  [test].[dbo].[@weekcounter]
) all_salesman_weeks
left join [test].[dbo].[@ORDERLOG] D1 
    on (all_salesman_weeks.week = DATEPART(wk, d1.u_date) and DATEPART(yy, d1.u_date) > 2014)
    and convert(decimal,d1.U_slsm) = all_salesman_weeks.salesmannum 
order by all_salesman_weeks.Week, all_salesman_weeks.SalesmanNum
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the answer. Now I have to go learn about "cross join" and find out why it works...